# content size of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in which I've set the `contentSize` to the size of the screen initially. So does this mean that if I have an `UIImageView` inside the scroll view then it can't zoom bigger than the `contentSize` I've set?

Because I initially have a `UIScrollView` with a `contentSize` of the phone's dimension and when I zoom into an image, it does it just fine (I can see the `contentSize` grows bigger as I zoom in) but when I adjust it manually it can't. Why is this?

I think when I initially initialize the `UIScrollView` frame, the content size will be set to the frame's size, however it can grow dynamically as I zoom in. However when I try to set the `contentSize`, it seems that now it's fixed. The reason why I am asking this is because I have a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`, when I zoom in on the image and I rotate the image, I want the `contentSize` to reset. Question is how do I reset this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom level is set by the `zoomScale` property of the `UIScrollView`. Its maximum and minimum is set by `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` respectively.

If you're trying to set the zoom by setting the `contentSize` then you're doing it wrong. The `contentSize` should be set as if the zoom scale was `1.0` and then you'd just set the `zoomScale` property to be what you wanted so for example `2.0` if you wanted it zoomed in to 200%.

You're probably seeing `contentSize` change as you zoom because I think the scroll view reports it scaled to the current zoom scale.

Comment: I am not trying to set the zoom size by the contentSize. Here's what happened, on landscape I have an image, and then I zoomed in to that image and then I rotate the device. What I wanted to do is to reset the content size.

Comment: Oh I see. Then try setting the zoom level to 1.0, then set the content size, then set the zoom level back to what it was.

Comment: zoom level? how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean to be honest. Can you show some code please?

Comment: actually setting the zoom level to 1 fixed the issue